# Loading default XSLTForms subform on body onload event

Tags: xsltforms

I'm trying to use subforms and I had a problem: I saw [the example provided in the oficcial XSLTForms](http://www.agencexml.com/xsltforms/writers.xml) but in that case the elements that load/unload the forms are always in the "main form" and, in my case, I need them to desappear, because I'm trying to build something like a wizard, So the first subform must desappear when the user press "Next" and then subform2 is loaded, and so on. This presents two problems:

1) If I include the first subform elements in the "main page", when I press the trigger the elements of subform1 are never unloaded. The other subforms do it, but that initial one is treated as part of the structure that never changes... And I really need to desappear. SO I think I have to put all the content of subform1 outside, in a separate xml and load it in the same way as the other subforms, but there is another problem:

2) I need it be loaded by default, and I tryed to put a load element directly in the main form body, but it didn't work.

I "patched it" temporally with a trigger in the main form, which loads the firms subform, but it is so... ugly, and I still have the same problem: I can navigate through subforms but that initial trigger never dissapears... So, any idea will be welcome! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<xf:model xmlns="" >
    <xf:action ev:event="xforms-ready">
        <xf:load show="embed" targetid="subform" resource="FirstSubform.xml"/> 
    </xf:action>
</xf:model>
```